# .net core httpClient get async. always response crashed JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, response, dotnet-httpclient

I converted the JSON to C# class

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("market")]
    public string Market { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("candle_date_time_utc")]
    public DateTime CandleDateTimeUtc { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("candle_date_time_kst")]
    public DateTime CandleDateTimeKst { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("opening_price")]
    public double OpeningPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("high_price")]
    public double HighPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("low_price")]
    public double LowPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("trade_price")]
    public double TradePrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    public object Timestamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("candle_acc_trade_price")]
    public double CandleAccTradePrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("candle_acc_trade_volume")]
    public double CandleAccTradeVolume { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("unit")]
    public int Unit { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("…_price")]
    public double? Price { get; set; }
}
```

```
[JsonProperty("…_price")]
        public double? Price { get; set; }
```

Responed JSON always crashed like it.

When I create new project, and request same thing with `httClient`.

It return JSON like it (not crashed):

```
public class MyArray
{
    [JsonProperty("market")]
    public string Market { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("candle_date_time_utc")]
    public DateTime CandleDateTimeUtc { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("candle_date_time_kst")]
    public DateTime CandleDateTimeKst { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("opening_price")]
    public double OpeningPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("high_price")]
    public double HighPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("low_price")]
    public double LowPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("trade_price")]
    public double TradePrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    public object Timestamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("candle_acc_trade_price")]
    public double CandleAccTradePrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("candle_acc_trade_volume")]
    public double CandleAccTradeVolume { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("unit")]
    public int Unit { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("MyArray")]
    public List<MyArray> MyArray { get; set; }
}
```

I don't know what wrong with my project.. is response `successStatusCode` but returned content is always crashed.. but create new project and request same thing with `httClient` it return difference JSON like second C# class (correct JSON).

Comment: post the error or the exception you're getting

Comment: You didn't post any code or exception. Post the actual code that throws and the *full* exception text. Not just the message but the full exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()`. `Always Crashed` isn't an error description. The problem may have nothing to do with JSON or HttpClient - perhaps you're trying to access a null property? We can't guess

Comment: I bet it's a wrong url

Comment: Does the JSON text have a `_price` property *at all*? Using underscore as a prefix in JSON s *very* unusual

Comment: not wrong url. I request the same url at new project file. it response the correct json

Comment: response.content.tostringasync() not return Exception.

Comment: `
using (HttpClient httclinet = new())
            {
                httclinet.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.upbit.com");
                var response = await httclinet.GetAsync("/v1/candles/minutes/3?market=KRW-BTC&count=14");
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
`
Same way.  on ProjectA  return crashed json.  On ProjectB return current json

Comment: @otterotter post your code in the question itself. It's impossible to read coce in comments and what you posted doesn't seam to even have the characters `Json`, much less try to parse anything.  You said the application crashed. That means an exception was thrown. Post that as well. Post enough code so others can reproduce the problem. `on ProjectA return crashed json. On ProjectB return current json` different projects, different code, different results.

Comment: I Tested it. it's blazor problem when I call this api with blazor. it's always chrashed but with console project or the other project is no problem.

Comment: Hi @otterotter, do you really know what is your question? From you description, it seems caused deserialization error by two different models. I cannot see anything related to the httpclient. Please ask the clear question and provide enough code.